# geom_bar only show specific stacks of interest

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to make a bar plot with my data.
My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame("sampleID" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), 
                 "Type" = c("A","B","E","A","B","C","D","A","C","D","F","B","C","E","F"), 
                 "Frequency" = c(10,2,1,5,7,1,6,8,4,3,1,6,5,2,6))
```

I've plotted this using:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=sampleID, y=Frequency, fill=Type)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

which gives me this plot:
[image]

Now I'm trying to figure out how to *only leave most two frequent `Type`s and `Type E` stacks* in each of the `sample ID` bars, and make the rest of them `Other`s.

(For instance, for `sampleID == 1`, `A` and `B` are the two most frequent `Type`s and `E` is the remaining one, so all three stacks will show up in my final plot. But for `sampleID == 2`, `B` and `D` are the two most frequent `Type`s and there's no `E`, so `B` and `D` stacks will show up in my final plot, while `A` and `C` will be converted to `Other`. Or for `sampleID == 4`, `B`, `E` and `F` stacks will stay in my final plot, while `C` will be converted to `Other`.)

I've found other examples of using `slice` to keep the top frequencies but I couldn't figure out how to apply that to each `sampleID`, not across the whole `df`, and I couldn't find any examples of explicitly forcing `geom_bar` to show a specific stack. Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define this little helper function:

```r
top2_or_e <- function(x) {
   x$Type[-unique(c(order(-x$Frequency)[1:2], which(x$Type == "E")))] <- "other"
   x
}
```

Then you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

ggplot(data = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$sampleID), top2_or_e)),
       aes(x = sampleID, y = Frequency, fill = Type)) +
   geom_col(color = "gray50") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(6, "Pastel1"), "gray50")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very neat solution! I just found an additional problem I have with my actual dataset that I failed to reproduce in my test dataset. R is alphabetically sorting `Type`, and in the example, the `other` stacks happened to be the last in alphabetical order (e.g. in `sampleID == 2`, `other` is `C` and `D` so they are stacked together below `A` and `B`). But in my actual data, the gray stacks are scattered throughout the bars because the alphabetical order is messed up. Would there be a way to arrange the data so that anything except the `top2` or `e` will always be plotted at the bottom?